# how changing the default editor via puppet

Tags: puppet, vim

I'm trying to find the best way with Puppet to change the default editor on all machines(Ubuntu & RedHat) so that any user is constrained to use a type of editor. And to keep it possible to change editor for its own use.

The goal, avoid the message below When I invoke "crontab -e".
and get vim instead :

```
$ crontab -e
Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/ed
  2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  3. /usr/bin/jove
  4. /usr/bin/vim.basic
  5. /usr/bin/vim.tiny
```

Here's a proposal via puppet:

```
    class vim {
      package { vim:
        ensure => present,
      }

      file { "/etc/vim/vimrc":
        owner   => root,
        group   => root,
        mode    => 644,
        source  => "puppet:///vim/vimrc",
        require => Package["vim"],
      }

      exec { "update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/vim.basic":
        unless => "test /etc/alternatives/editor -ef /usr/bin/vim.basic"
      }
    }
```

Any comments or remarks are welcome. many thanks.

Comment: So does that work or not?

Comment: Note that can also set *EDITOR* environment variable per-user, put for example 

    EDITOR=vim

to their ~/.bashrc.

Comment: And if you wanted a system-wide default value for `$EDITOR`, you could export it in some file under `/etc/profile.d`.